# Как ввести символ `~` в виртуальном терминале

Tags: debian, клавиатура, терминал

Сервер Debian, виртуальный терминал.

**/etc/default/keyboard:**

```
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us,de,fr,ua,ru"
XKBVARIANT="intl"
XKBOPTIONS=""
BACKSPACE="guess"
```

Не все символы соответствуют физической раскладке стандартной `en/ru` клавиатуры, символ тильда (`~`) не вводится.

[Здесь](https://wiki.debian.org/ru/Keyboard) проблема не описана. Способ, описанный [здесь](http://dry.sailingissues.com/us-international-keyboard-layout.html), не работает.

Прошу совета, что нужно сделать, чтобы виртуальную раскладку привести в соответствие физической (в частном случае, как ввести нужный мне символ)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл клавиши ввода тильды:

```
F6, F12, etc...
```

Описание есть [здесь](https://superuser.com/questions/190025/how-can-i-type-tilde-in-the-ubuntu-terminal-with-a-norwegian-keyboard).